# Gnome3 File Manager Not Working (Debian / Kali)

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, gnome3, nautilus

2 days ago after updating linux, gnome file manager does not open. When I want to open anything under the "places" option at the top (home-documents-download-desktop ...), it tries to open it with "chirp", but it can't be opened naturally.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru4gk.png)

I've tried everything I know, but nothing changed. Methods I have applied;

- `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get full-upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`
- `apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove --purge`

  - `apt-get --purge remove`
  - `apt-get install gnome-core kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base`
  - `apt-get -f install --reinstall`
  - `tracker reset -r`
  - `tracker reset -e`
  - `dpkg --configure -a`
  - Live CD(USB) Recovery Mode

I think the problem is an update, but I'm wondering if there is any other way I can solve it.

**EDIT**: [https://bugs.kali.org](https://bugs.kali.org/my_view_page.php) - https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=5736 the situation has been reported by users on the page and there seems to be no manual solution at the moment. I wanted to give information if there are people who have the same problem. I hope they will fix the problem with the update.

Comment: Please note that this is not a forum. If you've solved your problem, please use the button below and answer your own question.

Comment: Are you able to open the file manager directly as an app (e.g. opening a terminal and then running `nautilus`)?

Comment: With yesterday's update, the issue was fixed. **The path to follow:** `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get full-upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` **If the problem persists:** `apt-get -f install --reinstall nautilus*` @grawity